# tableView.scrollToRow(...) with callback

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

everyone.

Is there a way to get a callback when `tableView.scrollToRow(...)` or `tableView.setContentOffset(...)` animation completed?

**Please read the whole question ↓ not only the title :)**

I know about delegate method `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` and it doesn't work in my case: I have a few different calls of `scrollToRow(...)` and need to execute the proper block of code after each. Thus, using `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(...)` will cause overcomplicated logic.

I also know about wrapping `tableView.scrollToRow(...)` into a `UIView.animate()` which has callback closure. But in this case, tableView doesn't generate delegate event of `scrollViewDidScroll(...)` which I listen to for proper interface updates.

That's why I'm digging in the direction of having a callback after regular `tableView.scrollToRow(...)`. Is there a way to get what I need?

Comment: You can check with UIScrollView delegate methods. They will call once you call tableView.scrollToRow(...) or tableView.setContentOffset(...) methods.

Comment: You can use all scrollView delegate methods

Comment: func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView!) is the main method through which you can achieve your requirement

Comment: @SivajeeBattina Delegate-based solution won't work. From [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow#discussion): *Invoking this method does not cause the delegate to receive a scrollViewDidScroll(_:) message*.

Comment: @SivajeeBattina as I wrote in the question, I'd like to avoid using delegate methods.